# What is the difference between $n $ (no. of photons passing a fixed point per second) and $f$ (frequency) of a photon in the formula: power = $nhf$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons

As above. As far as I understand, the frequency of a wave is also the number of waves passing a fixed point per second.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a misconception. The  number of photons, $n$, passing a fixed point is exactly that, and is a different entity than the frequency.
By definition, frequency (in general terms) is the amount of times a cycle occurs in a given interval. In photons, we refer to frequency as the amount of times it oscillates in a second, due to its wavelike nature. Its energy is described as 
$$E_{photon}=hf$$

However, you must take into consideration that frequency by itself can be applied to many situations. You could measure the frequency with which waves pass a given point, and call it $f$. However, it would NOT be the same as the frequency of oscillation of the wave (as you could have several waves, in your case photons, passing through).

Basically, whenever you are calculating power you need to know the rate at which energy is provided or consumed in a given amount of time. In your case, you wish to know how much power is provided by the n photons that pass per seconds. So $f$ is the frequency of the photon that gives you the energy of said photon, and $n$ is the amount of photons that pass per seconds (or frequency of the passage of photons, but you must we careful when using frequency twice in the same sentence, as it can lead to confusion).

Comment: So what is 1 photon defined as in terms of a wave? And how does this differ from a single oscillation?

Comment: @physicsgrind You may want to post that as a separate question, as the answer is deep, nuanced, and not at all brief.

Comment: If we have 10 crests of a wave  passing a point per second, when is that not a 10 Hz wave?

Comment: @Photon Sure. But that doesn't mean ten photons.

Comment: @dmckee, I'm asking about the last paragraph of the answer where he says, "You could measure the frequency with which a wave passes a given point, and call it f. However, it would NOT be the same as the frequency of oscillation of the wave (not in general, at least)." As far as I can see, there's nothing about photons being discussed here.

Comment: @Photon Uhm. He may be discussion wave packets which have some surprising properties if you are used to considering only the behavior of pure harmonic waves (this is related to the difference between phase velocity and group velocity). If that is not his intent then I suspect it is an error.

Comment: @dmckee, I had the same thought, but I think the answer should be written to be more clear if that's what is meant.

Comment: @dmckee, if you had a string of wave packets each with only a small number of crests, but separated by many times the fundamental period, you'd have fewer crests passing than the fundamental frequency would suggest. But that's a pretty specific scenario.

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct. I have edited in order to better express what I intended. I hope that it is now clear. Thanks for the comments!